# Using lappy to do loop glm

Tags: r, logistic-regression

This is an example of what I'm trying to do.

## Step 1 :

Create a list of combination of dependent variable and independent variables

```
a <- list(paste("Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width" ) , 
paste("Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length" )
)
```

## Step 2 :

Using lappy function to run glm for each element in the list in the step #1 , and also create a for loop to test two different parameters

```
param <- c("gaussian" , "Gamma" )
for(i in 1:2) {
print(lapply(a , FUN = function(X) glm(X , data = iris ,family = param[i]    )))}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this without using for loop in the second step? This is what I have tried but it's not working.

```
a <- 
list(
paste("Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width , data = iris , family = "Gaussian" " ) , 
paste("Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width , data = iris , family = "Gamma" " ) ,                  
paste("Sepal.Width ~  Sepal.Length , data = iris , family = "Gaussian" " ) ,
paste("Sepal.Width ~  Sepal.Length , data = iris , family = "Gamma" " ) 
)

lapply(a , FUN = function(X) glm(X))
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `paste` does nothing here. Leave it out. Furthermore, the use of strings is also unnecessary here. Leave them out. Same goes for your parameter families: these are *functions*, no need to quote them.

This already vastly simplifies the code, both in length and conceptually. Now we have this:

```
models = list(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length)
families = c(gaussian, Gamma)
```

And we can apply it:

```
lapply(models,
       function (model) lapply(families,
                               function (family) glm(model, family, iris)))
```

… which is a nested application. The indentation hints at what belongs together. Since this is a bit odd, we can also use the cartesian product of the different parameters:

```
params = as.data.frame(t(expand.grid(models, families)))

lapply(params, function (p) glm(formula = p[[1]], data = iris, family = p[[2]]))
```

The first line is a bit obscure here. `expand.grid` allows us to create a data frame of all parameter combinations. Here’s an example:

```
> expand.grid(1 : 3, c('a', 'b'))

  Var1 Var2
1    1    a
2    2    a
3    3    a
4    1    b
5    2    b
6    3    b
```

Unfortunately, this data frame is in the wrong orientation to be used by `lapply`, because that applies over columns. So we `t`ranspose it (and convert it to a `data.frame` again, since `t` always returns a `matrix`).

This piece of code is incredibly useful because it makes writing nested loops via `lapply` much more readable; unfortunately, it is itself quite unreadable, so we stick it into a function:

```
combine_parameters = function (...)
    as.data.frame(t(expand.grid(...)))
```

This allows us to write elegant, readable code:

```
models = list(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length)
families = c(gaussian, Gamma)
params = combine_parameters(models, families)
lapply(params, function (p) glm(formula = p[[1]], family = p[[2]]), data = iris)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using lapply:

```
lapply(c("gaussian", "Gamma"), function(myFamily){
  lapply(c("Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width" , 
           "Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length"), function(myFormula){
             glm(formula = myFormula, family = myFamily, data = iris)
           })
})
```

---

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in @KonradRudolph answer, we can pass formula as a list with a `link =` argument, e.g.:

```
lapply(list(gaussian(link = "identity"), Gamma), function(myFamily){
  lapply(c("Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width" , 
           "Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length"), function(myFormula){
             glm(formula = myFormula, family = myFamily, data = iris)
           })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @zx8754 for your answer. Also, I try to do the same but adding the link function as well i.e. link = log and link = identity. It's not working properly when using nested lapply.